# EIP712-- Sign/Recovery using ethereumJS/Solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs, ecrecover

I've tried to mirror the example as shown: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/tree/master/assets/eip-712

However after much attempt at troubleshooting I have been unable to return the correct address using ecrecover in my solidity code.

My Javascript code: https://gist.github.com/JTraversa/a88edab6f7d9457317928483e78d8681

My Solidity code: https://gist.github.com/JTraversa/cdb23d98755738ff460c3c5805647b34

At this point, I believe the issue is likely to do with the data hashing in Solidity, though for the life of me I cant identify what.

If not that, perhaps a mismatch of the data types between the solidity/js hashing. i.e. hashed as a string in javascript but bytes in solidity?

I can identify more specific blocks of code, however given the snippets are relatively short and I am unsure where the issue lays, I'm assuming the full snippets are more useful.

Ive been at this for quite awhile so any help is very appreciated. I am more than happy to provide a generous tip if anyone can help!

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I'm battling a similar situation currently; I can sign and recover the address totally in the browser but I must be doing something wrong in the solidity side since I am not getting the correct recovered address.

Comment: Yep :) https://swivel.finance


Though I dont remember the *specific* issue, for the most part common issues are related to the correct abi encoding.


I'd recommend using ethers or just plain window.ethereum for signing the object, and then either try to replicate someone else's on-chain encoding.


Ours is available here: https://github.com/Swivel-Finance/gost/blob/adapters/test/swivel/Hash.sol